# Google API Client Libraries API Key Security and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-data-api

In the Google API Client Libraries sample documentation it has the API key directly inside the code as shown here
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples.

However, in the best practices documentation it says specifically to not do that. I have been pondering ways to successfully separate and secure the API key, but it adds significant overhead by essentially requiring a server side proxy that performs the api call and returns the response. This is all well and good until you also want to include pagination tokens with the response to allow quicker responses by not requesting the whole response. Does anyone have any ideas for securing the API Key in javascript?